# How to make navbar overlap other contents in tailwind css

Tags: css, forms, navbar, tailwind-css

When I open my nav bar(for mobile version) on my first page it works fine and overlaps the contents (picture): https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/916242216211595264/1001057465795874906/unknown.png
And when I open my navbar on the second page(forms page) the forms overlap the navbar.(picture): https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/916242216211595264/1001057531591929876/unknown.png
How could I fix that?
My code for my navbar is:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi';
import {AiOutlineClose} from 'react-icons/ai';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='flex sticky justify-between items-center h-20 max-w-full mx-auto px-4 text-white  top-0'>
      
        <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/logo192.png"} alt="none" className='w-9'/>
        <ul className='hidden  md:flex'>
            <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active" ><li className='p-4 mx-5 cursor-pointer after:content-[" "] after:absolute after:w-[45px] after:scale-x-0 after:h-[2px] after:flex after:bg-indigo-600 after:origin-bottom-left after:transition-[0.5s] after:ease-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:scale-110 hover:after:origin-bottom-right hover:text-indigo-600 '>Home</li></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/details" activeClassName="active" ><li className='p-4 mx-5 cursor-pointer after:content-[" "] after:absolute after:w-[45px] after:scale-x-0 after:h-[2px] after:flex after:bg-indigo-600 after:origin-bottom-left after:transition-[0.5s] after:ease-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:scale-110 hover:after:origin-bottom-right hover:text-indigo-600 '>About</li></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="https://www.google.com" activeClassName="active" ><li className='p-4 mx-5 cursor-pointer after:content-[" "] after:absolute after:w-[35px] after:scale-x-0 after:h-[2px] after:flex after:bg-indigo-600 after:origin-bottom-left after:transition-[0.5s] after:ease-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:scale-110 hover:after:origin-bottom-right hover:text-indigo-600 '>Host</li></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/info" activeClassName="active"><li className='p-4 mx-5 cursor-pointer after:content-[" "] after:absolute after:w-[55px] after:scale-x-0 after:h-[2px] after:flex after:bg-indigo-600 after:origin-bottom-left after:transition-[0.5s] after:ease-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:scale-110 hover:after:origin-bottom-right hover:text-indigo-600'>Tutorial</li></NavLink>
        </ul>
      
        <div onClick={toggle} className='block md:hidden'>
          {!isOpen ? <AiOutlineClose size={20}/> : <GiHamburgerMenu size={20}/>}
        </div>
        
        <div className={!isOpen ? 'fixed left-0 top-1 w-[60%] h-full border-r border-r-gray-800 bg-gray-900 ease-in-out duration-500' : 'fixed left-[-100%] ease-in-out duration-500'}>
        <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/logo192.png"} alt="none" className='w-9 left-0'/>
        <ul className='uppercase p-4'>
            <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-700 hover:border-white hover:transition-[0.5s] hover:ease-in-out'>Home</li>
            <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-700 hover:border-white hover:transition-[0.5s] hover:ease-in-out'>About</li>
            <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-700 hover:border-white hover:transition-[0.5s] hover:ease-in-out'>Host</li>
            <li className='p-4 hover:border-b hover:border-white hover:transition-[0.5s] hover:ease-in-out'>Tutorial</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar;
```

First page:

```
import React from 'react'
import Typed from 'react-typed';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
export const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white">
        <div
          id="index"
          className="index max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center"
        >
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className="md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6">
              Web
            </h1>
            <Typed
              className="md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6 text-indigo-600"
              strings={["site", "Adam"]}
              typeSpeed={70}
              backSpeed={100}
              loop
            />
          </div>
          <p className="md:text-3xl sm:text-2xl text-xl font-bold py-4 ">
          A website  that is focused on <a className="underline text-indigo-600">design</a> and 
            <a className="underline text-indigo-600"> simplicity</a>
          </p>
          <Link to="/details"><button className="bg-white text-black w-[200px] transition-[0.5s] rounded-lg font-bold my-6 mx-auto py-3 ring-2 ring-white hover:ring-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-600  hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-indigo-700 hover:text-white hover:scale-110">
            Create
          </button></Link>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Forms Page:
Code from: https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/sign-in-forms (First Form). So how could i make my navbar overlap my forms page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to work with `relative` `absolute` and `z-index` tailwind classes to overlap the navbar on the contents of the page.

#### Logic:

Have parent `relative` having `z-index` value less than the child `absolute` div which will be used for navbar.

#### Output in large device:

[image]

#### Output in smaller device:

[image]

#### Code:

```
    <div class="md:bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="invisible md:visible bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 md:invisible"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Further more you can use this [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/N8yjIUHXVT) link

---

### Extra. Toggle mobile navbar using hamburger menu

#### Output on large devices

[image]

#### Output in small device with `hamburger menu`

[image: Enter description]

#### When clicked on `hamburger menu`

[image]

#### Code:

```
  <body>
    <div class="bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex">
      <div class="hidden md:block bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl pl-24 md:p-0 main_content">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="mobile_navbar absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 hidden md:hidden"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="md:hidden space-y-2 absolute hamburger_menu inset-y-0 left-0 p-4"
      >
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document
        .querySelector(".hamburger_menu")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          console.log("Hello");
          document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden");
        });

      document.querySelector(".main_content").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Touch me");
        console.log(
          document
            .querySelector(".mobile_navbar")
            .classList.contains("hidden") == false &&
            document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden")
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the z-index of the nav bar so that it is higher than that of the form.